# Live network graph update

Tags: highcharts

I'm having issue when it comes to update a network graph from live data.

I need to keep existing points if they already exists, in order to avoid a glitch which makes points to move at each data update.

The first thing I tried is using serie.update:

```js
const dataset = {
   "nodes":[
      {
         "id":"5a922c64-43b3-41b5-8b00-0ec999b58d5c",
         "name":"AWS",
         "dataLabels":{
            "y":50
         },
         "drilldown":true,
         "className":"provider",
         "category":"providers",
         "labelRank":1
      },
      {
         "id":"421103ae-f3b9-41ef-b569-d3466c243fa3",
         "name":"Frankfurt",
         "dataLabels":{
            "y":40
         },
         "drilldown":true,
         "className":"region",
         "category":"regions",
         "labelRank":2
      },
      {
         "id":"cd1c461201724c84bc7e5afa1177586a",
         "name":"Infallible Hofstadter",
         "className":"router",
         "dataLabels":{
            "y":40
         },
         "category":"routers",
         "drilldown":false,
         "labelRank":4
      }
   ],
   "data":[
      {
         "from":"5a922c64-43b3-41b5-8b00-0ec999b58d5c",
         "to":"421103ae-f3b9-41ef-b569-d3466c243fa3"
      },
      {
         "from":"421103ae-f3b9-41ef-b569-d3466c243fa3",
         "to":"cd1c461201724c84bc7e5afa1177586a"
      }
   ]
};

function requestData() {
  const serie = chart.series.at(0);
  serie.update(dataset);

  console.log('Data : ', serie.data);
  console.log('Points', serie.points);
  console.log('Nodes : ', serie.nodes);
}

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'networkgraph',
        marginTop: 80,
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Live network graph update - Update serie'
    },
   
    plotOptions: {
        networkgraph: {
            keys: ['from', 'to'],
                allowPointSelect: false,
                name: 'Router list',
                layoutAlgorithm: {
                    enableSimulation: true,
                    initialPositions: 'circle',
                    integration: 'verlet',
                }
        },
       
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'networkgraph',
      data: []
    }]
});
setTimeout(requestData, 1000);
```

```css
#container {
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/networkgraph.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/41wvq62t/8/

But this method redraw the whole graph, which is not the intended behavior. An alternative is by updating each point individually, but it does not seems to work well.

A reproduction case can be found here:

```js
const dataset = {
   "nodes":[
      {
         "id":"5a922c64-43b3-41b5-8b00-0ec999b58d5c",
         "name":"AWS",
         "dataLabels":{
            "y":50
         },
         "drilldown":true,
         "className":"provider",
         "category":"providers",
         "labelRank":1
      },
      {
         "id":"421103ae-f3b9-41ef-b569-d3466c243fa3",
         "name":"Frankfurt",
         "dataLabels":{
            "y":40
         },
         "drilldown":true,
         "className":"region",
         "category":"regions",
         "labelRank":2
      },
      {
         "id":"cd1c461201724c84bc7e5afa1177586a",
         "name":"Infallible Hofstadter",
         "className":"router",
         "dataLabels":{
            "y":40
         },
         "category":"routers",
         "drilldown":false,
         "labelRank":4
      }
   ],
   "data":[
      {
         "from":"5a922c64-43b3-41b5-8b00-0ec999b58d5c",
         "to":"421103ae-f3b9-41ef-b569-d3466c243fa3"
      },
      {
         "from":"421103ae-f3b9-41ef-b569-d3466c243fa3",
         "to":"cd1c461201724c84bc7e5afa1177586a"
      }
   ]
};

function requestData() {
    
  const serie = chart.series.at(0);
  // serie.update(dataset.value);
  // // Add new points
  // serie.setData(dataset.value.data, false);
  dataset.data.forEach((edge) => {
      const existingPoint = serie.points.find(
          (p) => p.from === edge.from && p.to === edge.to
      );
      if (!existingPoint) {
          console.log('Add point', edge);
          serie.addPoint(edge, false);
      } else if (!existingPoint.visible) {
      console.log('Make point visible');
          existingPoint.visible = true;
      }
  });

  // Remove unused points
  [...serie.points].forEach((point) => {
      if (
          !dataset.value.data.find(
              (d) => d.from === point.from && d.to === point.to
          )
      ) {
          point.visible = false;
      }
  });
  console.log('Data : ', serie.data);
  console.log('Points', serie.points);
  console.log('Nodes : ', serie.nodes);
  serie.redraw();
}

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'networkgraph',
        marginTop: 80,
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Live network graph update - Update points'
    },
   
    plotOptions: {
        networkgraph: {
            keys: ['from', 'to'],
                allowPointSelect: false,
                name: 'Router list',
                layoutAlgorithm: {
                    enableSimulation: true,
                    initialPositions: 'circle',
                    integration: 'verlet',
                }
        },
       
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'networkgraph',
      data: []
    }]
});
setTimeout(requestData, 1000);
```

```css
#container {
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/networkgraph.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/41wvq62t/7/

The idea behind keeping point is to allow the user to move them according its needs, then store node position and reuse it for further map usage.

Has someone managed to get a similar case to work?

Comment: Hi @Nico, In your second way, `series.redraw()` causes redrawing the whole graph, use `chart.redraw()` instead. Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/46zbrphx/

Comment: Make sense! Thanks! I'll share a jsfiddle with all the things I've been asking for once done :)